# update html page with SAS

Tags: html, sas

I have a lot of SAS programs that output the result to an external HTML file. If I re-run a program I have to press the F5 key to se the new update on an open HTML page. 
Is there a way to let the SAS program also updating the html page on the pc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your SAS programs interactively (either in Display Manager or in Enterprise Guide), you can set it to show you the results in your SAS session directly; in DM, choose Tools Menu->Options->Preferences, Results tab, select `View results as they are generated`.  If you are in Enterprise Guide, Tools Menu -> Options -> Results General, uncheck "Link handcoded ODS Results" (which will cause them to be brought into your session automatically).

In terms of what you can do in the browser, if you're writing complex HTML code (ie, you know how to include raw html), you could code in an automatic refresh, similar to how ESPN or whatnot automatically refreshes game score pages.  The basic concept is to include this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

in the `<head>` section.  That will cause it to refresh every 5 seconds.  This is not a good idea for your final production output (as your client's page will refresh constantly), but if you can make sure it's only there during testing, it should work.

Comment: I use BASE SAS (old fashion program window). I have to look at the output on the HTML page, because that how the setup is with links to start other sas program etc.

Comment: That's the Display Manager, then.  What version?

Comment: 9.2. It would be nice to be able to write some code at the end of the program that updated the page (F5).

Comment: We have some programs that execute VBA code from SAS. So a VBA solution might also work.

Comment: Yes, it works inside SAS. But we want to se the result opdated on the external html page in Internet Explorer. It would be a nice little improvement, so we could spare tabing F5 (and sometimes you think you have tabed F5 and get a wrong picture).

Comment: First off, inside SAS is actually using Internet Explorer to render the page (or whatever browser you chose), so there shouldn't be any differences.  Second, try the second half of my solution, then.